# Delete repeating data C# to SQL conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server

I just need to delete repeating user info from database. My c# code is below, but I just wonder how to achieve this in SQL rather without using cursor. I think the trick starts with the fetching the first rows or the remaining rows of the whole repeating datasets separated by email.

In C#, I gather repeating emails by groups of 1000 and delete the remaining rows after skipping the first one.

```
List<string> top1000_emails;
do
{
  top1000_emails = sql.dbCommand.GetFirstColumn<string>(@"select top 1000 email
      from UserBase
      group by email
      having COUNT(email) > 1");

  for (int i = 0; i < top1000_emails.Count; i++)
  {
     var tmpids = sql.dbCommand.GetFirstColumn<long>("select [Id] from UserBase where email = {0}", top1000_emails[i]).Skip(1);
     sql.dbCommand.DeleteByIds<UserBase>(tmpids);
   }
} while (top1000_emails.Count > 0);
```

Comment: So your point is to keep one distinct email record and delete any other duplicate records? It can be done in SQL queries, I don't think you need that C# code.

Comment: Exactly , I just need to keep the distinct emails and delete the other     repeatings.So how can I do in sql without cursor.Because if I use cursor , it will be the same as my c# code

Comment: Is there any unique Id in table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do ti simply through SQL, like this (if you have SQL Server 2005 or higher):

```
;WITH a AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY Id) RowNum
    FROM    UserBase
)
-- deleted rows will be:
SELECT  *
--DELETE 
FROM    a
WHERE   a.RowNum <> 1
```

Comment: If he is using SQL Server 2005 or greater!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
 --delete userbase 
 select * 
 from userbase
    left join (select email, MIN(id) minid from userbase group by email) mins
    on userbase.id = mins.minid
    and userbase.email = mins.email
 where mins.email is null
```

Take a backup of your data first, just in case 
Then replace the select with the delete

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have Primary key, ID, in your UserBase Table. Create UserBase_Unique Table exact structure as UserBase Table and run the following command. UserBase_Unique table will have the result you are looking for.

```
INSERT INTO UserBase_Unique (ID,Email)

SELECT Min(ID)
FROM UserBase AS U
WHERE Exists (SELECT email, Count(ID)
FROM UserBase U2
WHERE U2.email= U2.email
GROUP BY email
HAVING Count(U2.ID) > 1)
GROUP BY email;
```